# python 3.6 large files

Tags: python-3.x, file

I am using python 3.6. I am retrieving and opening a large url file. I have not included the entire code but the last three lines of code will work fine if the url file is small. for large files I get an error message.
can anyone tell me where the error comes from?

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(daturl)
content = response.read().decode()

list_of_dict = []
for s in content.splitlines():
    if len(s) <= 1:
        continue
    list_of_dict.append(json.loads(s))

# Print all of the data
print(get_data(list_of_dict,10))

# Stuff it into variables and print it all
typ, tme, id, amt = get_data(list_of_dict,900)
print(typ,tme,id,amt)


for i in range(len(list_of_dict)):
    if list_of_dict[i]["event_type"] == 'befriend':
        print(list_of_dict[i]["id1"], list_of_dict[i]["id2"])
```

## Output:

```
('purchase', '2017-06-14 18:46:40', '7045', '24.11')
purchase 2017-06-14 18:46:40 2299 61.74

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-e03917b4027c> in <module>()
     26 
     27 for i in range(len(list_of_dict)):
---> 28     if list_of_dict[i]["event_type"] == 'befriend':
     29         print(list_of_dict[i]["id1"], list_of_dict[i]["id2"])
     30 

KeyError: 'event_type'**
```

Comment: Clearly one of your dicts doesn't have the `event_type` property. Check through your input file.

Comment: Hi it does have the event_type. I think now after checking the file that the first line might have caused the problem since the difference between the two files is that first line

Comment: How can I skip the first line of content after the command  content.splitlines() to  append all the data with list_of_dict.append(json.loads(s)) except the ones at line1

Comment: You should really ask that as a separate question. The first thought is to use `for s in content.splitlines()[1:]:` and appropriately update your `if` condition.

Comment: Thanks, the comment is already helpful (I am not very python 3.6 proficient or a programmer).